# Avoid ConstraintViolationException in JPA and OneToMany relationship when merge

Tags: java, hibernate, postgresql, jpa, one-to-many

What I want to achieve with the example below is to avoid the constraint violation exception that occurs
when run the following:

```
Parent p = new Parent();
Set<Child> children = new HashSet<Child>();
Child c = new Child();
children.add(c);
p.setChildren(children);

entityManager.merge(p);
entityManager.merge(p);
```

How to configure JPA to achieve this effect? Below are the classes.

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "parent", indexes = {uniqueConstraints = { @UniqueConstraint(columnNames = { "uri" }) })
public class Parent implements Serializable {
  ...
  private String uri;
  private Set<Child> children = new HashSet<Child>();


  @Id
  @Column(name = "id", unique = true)
  @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "parent_seq")
  @SequenceGenerator(name = "parent_seq", sequenceName = "parent_seq", allocationSize = 1)
  public Long getId() {
    return id;
  }

  @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval = true)
  @JoinColumn(name = "parent_id")
  public Set<Child> getChildren() {
    return children;
  }

@Override
  public boolean equals(Object obj) {
        if (this == obj)
            return true;
        if (obj == null)
            return false;
        if (getClass() != obj.getClass())
            return false;
        Parent other = (Parent) obj;
        if (uri == null) {
            if (other.uri != null)
                return false;
        } else if (!uri.equals(other.uri))
            return false;
        return true;
    }


@Override
    public int hashCode() {
        final int prime = 31;
        int result = 1;
        result = prime * result + ((uri == null) ? 0 : uri.hashCode());
        return result;
    }



}

@Entity
@Table(name = "child", indexes = {uniqueConstraints = { @UniqueConstraint(columnNames = { "text" }) })
public class Child implements Serializable {

  private String text;

  @Id
  @Column(name = "id", unique = true)
  @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "child_seq")
  @SequenceGenerator(name = "child_seq", sequenceName = "child_seq", allocationSize = 1)
  public Long getId() {
    return id;
  }



  @Override
  public boolean equals(Object obj) {
        if (this == obj)
            return true;
        if (obj == null)
            return false;
        if (getClass() != obj.getClass())
            return false;
        Child other = (Child) obj;
        if (text == null) {
            if (other.text != null)
                return false;
        } else if (!text.equals(other.text))
            return false;
        return true;
    }


@Override
    public int hashCode() {
        final int prime = 31;
        int result = 1;
        result = prime * result + ((text == null) ? 0 : text.hashCode());
        return result;
    }
}
```

I use postgres and hibernate as JPA provider

Comment: I dont which hibernate version you are using, but upto version 4.3.5, i still have problems with fetch=FetchType.LAZY on the @OneToMany annotation. and only works with @LazyCollection(LazyCollectionType.TRUE) hibernate equivalence

Comment: In my configuration I have class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaVendorAdapter" and the version of spring-orm is 4.0.4-RELEASE. Which according to this link should be Hibernate 4.3.5-Final - https://www.versioneye.com/java/org.springframework:spring-orm/4.0.4.RELEASE

Comment: I certainly want to do this with JPA, not Hibernate.

Comment: Hi I am facing same issue , cna you please share how did you resolve this?